# VS2012 Debugging asp.net app - Run as different user not working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, asp.net-development-serv

I am attempting to debug an asp.net application which uses Windows Authentication for security. To log in as the test user, I can  my browser icon to get the 'Run as different user' option. This works when accessing my test server, but when I attempt to use 'Run as different user' while debugging locally in VS2012 using the default ASP.NET Development Server it ignores the account that the browser is running as and uses my credentials.

Is there a way to run a browser as a different user for local debugging with ASP.NET Development Server? If not, what is the easiest way to set up local debugging to allow browser run as for testing?